# Run-time error 6 Overflow

Tags: vba

I have encountered this error even though all my data types seems fine.

> Run-time error 6 Overflow

Here is the function:

```
Function equation(x As Long) As Long

    Dim a As Long, b As Double

    a = Int(((x - 2) Mod 8) / 6) + 2 * Int((x - 2) / 8)
    b = (x + a - 1) / 2

    equation = Abs(4 * b + 5 + 2 * Int(b))

End Function
```

Error is encountered when `x = 572662307` it says overflow.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the `Int` function? It performs integer-truncation.

Comment: `572662307` is one-quarter towards the max value of a 32-bit signed integer (2 billion). In VBA `Long` is a 32-bit integer and is not a 64-bit integer as in C#. I recommend changing `x` to `Double`.

Comment: @Dai what is the substitute for this int? yes it is necessary cause i need only the integer part of the number after mod

Comment: maybe [LongLong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/longlong-data-type) data type will do

Comment: @DisplayName `LongLong` is not available in 32-bit Office.

Comment: @Dai yes, I know, that's why I posted the link to a page where it explains that. Let's see if Vincent can exploit it or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x = 572662307`. is one-quarter of the max value of a 32-bit signed integer (~2 billion) so your arithmetic operations will likely hit that indeed.

In VBA `Long` is a 32-bit signed integer and is not a 64-bit signed integer as in C#. I recommend changing both `a` and `x` to `Double`.

You could also spread-out your function so you can inspect all intermediate steps in your debugger:

```
Function equation(x As Double) As Double

    Dim a As Double, b As Double, c As Double, d As Double, e As Double, f As Double, g As Double

    a = (x - 2) Mod 8
    b = a / 6
    b = Int( b )

    c = (x - 2) / 8
    d = 2 * Int( c )

    e = b + d
    f = (x + a - 1)
    f = f / 2

    g = 4 * b + 5 + 2 * Int( f )
    equation = Abs( g )

End Function
```

Comment: but x is also >2billion also for a